# What are the iteration class methods next() and __next__() for, and what is the difference?

Tags: python, iterator

I am a little bit lost on python iterators. I occasionally use them, but I don't remember creating one myself. I read from somewhere that I don't remember where, a code like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = "initial_value"
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        # I don't quite remember what was here :S
        return self.something
```

I guess `__iter__()` method supposed to return an iterator, and that iterator should have a next method right? Then what about `__next__()` method? is it for directly iterating over a class without it returning another iterator with `__iter__()` method?

Comment: **foo** is an iterator. In this case it simply returns itself. An object can support iteration, but not be an iterator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[PEP 3114](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/) renamed `iterator.next()` to `iterator.__next__()`. This was implemented in version 3.0. The link above contains all the gory details.

Comment: I think you mean `iterator.__next__()` .  :-)

Answer (score 8):

`next` has been renamed to `__next__` in Python 3. As for what it does, it should return the next item, or raise `StopIteration` if there are no more.

Comment: How does this differ from __iter__() ?