# python 2 vs python 3 class with __iter__

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, iterator

I am trying to figure out how to make this class work in Python 3, it works in Python 2. This is from a tutorial by D. Beasley for generators. I am new to Python and just working through tutorials online.

Python 2

```
class countdown(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.count = start
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.count <= 0:
            raise StopIteration
        r = self.count
        self.count -= 1
        return r

c = countdown(5)

for i in c:
    print i,
```

Python 3, not working.

```
class countdown(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.count = start
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.count <= 0:
            raise StopIteration
        r = self.count
        self.count -= 1
        return r

c = countdown(5)

for i in c:
    print(i, end="")
```

Comment: This is also covered in the docs https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods

Comment: Similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223183/what-are-the-iteration-class-methods-next-and-next-for-and-what-is-the) from 2011.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The special method for iterators was renamed from `next` to `__next__` in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods) to match other special methods.

You can make it work on both versions without code changes by following the definition of `next` with:

```
__next__ = next
```

so each version of Python finds the name it expects.

Comment: Thanks, I was concentrating on __iter__ , as I thought that was the problem, and didn't research the "next" statement.